# Submit form with Kendo MVC Grid and other elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, user-interface, grid, kendo-ui

I am trying to get a form containing a Kendo MVC grid and other elements to submit.

- The View model contains contains three string fields and an `IEnumerable` collection.
- The grid is server bound.  I am not adding any elements or deleting any elements from the list using the grid but the grid contains a check box mapped to a boolean column in the list items.

Whenever I submit this form the three string elements return in the post method but the list is always null.

**Here is the data model:**

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ChildItems> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildItems
{
    public string ChildField1 { get; set; }
    public string ChildField2 { get; set; }
    public boolean Include { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is my View:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@model GridInForm.Models.Parent

@using(Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home"))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Editing Parent</legend>

        @Html.LabelFor(parent => parent.Field1)
        @Html.EditorFor(parent => parent.Field1)

        @Html.LabelFor(parent => parent.Field2)
        @Html.EditorFor(parent => parent.Field2)
        @Html.LabelFor(parent => parent.Comments)
        @Html.EditorFor(parent => parent.Comments)
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Children)
            .Name("Children")
            .ToolBar(tools => tools.Create().Text("Add new Children"))
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Bottom))
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.ChildField1).ClientTemplate("#= ChildField1 #" + 
                    "<input type='hidden' name='ChildField1[#= index(data)#].ChildField1' value='#= Name #' />"
                );

                columns.Bound(p => p.ChildField2).Hidden().ClientTemplate("#= ChildField1 #" +
                    "<input type='hidden' name='ChildField1[#= index(data)#].ChildField1' value='#= ChildField1 #' />"
                );

                columns.Command(command => 
                {
                    // command.Destroy();
                    command.Edit();
                }).Width(100);
            })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Server()
                .Create("Create", "Home")
                .Read("Index", "Home")
                .Update("Update", "Home")
                .Model(model => 
                {
                    model.Id(p => p.ChildField1);
                    model.Field(p => p.ChildField1).Editable(false);
                })
                //.ServerOperation(true)
            )
        )
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}

<script>
    function index(dataItem) {
        alert("bindind");
        var data = $("#Products").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
        return data.indexOf(dataItem);
    }
</script>
```

When I submit the form, I get the parent items back in the view model but the `IEnumerable` fields from the grid are always null.

Is this just not the way to do this, and if so what is the way to accomplish something like this?  I have had this issue on previous Telerik versions and I see it is the same on Kendo UI.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.  This has been a long going on issue.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a form I'm working on.  Any help would definitely be appreciated it.  This is annoyingly frustrating.

Answer (score 7):

I have exactly this scenario working perfectly in my project.  Here's my grid declaration...

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.ChildLines)
    .Name("RequestLinesGrid")
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.InCell))
         .Columns(columns =>
         {
             columns.Bound(p => p.ItemCode).ClientTemplate("#= ItemCode #" +
               "<input type='hidden' name='MyLines[#= index(data)#].ItemCode' value='#= ItemCode #' />"
             );
             columns.Bound(p => p.Description).ClientTemplate("#= Description #" +
               "<input type='hidden' name='MyLines[#= index(data)#].Description' value='#= Description #' />"
             );
             columns.Bound(p => p.UoM).ClientTemplate("#= UoM #" +
               "<input type='hidden' name='MyLines[#= index(data)#].UoM' value='#= UoM #' />"
             );
             columns.Bound(p => p.QtyCC).ClientTemplate("#= QtyCC #" +
                "<input type='hidden' name='MyLines[#= index(data)#].QtyCC' value='#= QtyCC #' />"
             );
             columns.Bound(p => p.QtyEmployee).ClientTemplate("#= QtyEmployee #" +
                "<input type='hidden' name='MyLines[#= index(data)#].QtyEmployee' value='#= QtyEmployee #' />"
             );
             columns.Bound(p => p.ItemListLineID).Hidden(true).ClientTemplate("#= ItemListLineID #" +
                "<input type='hidden' name='MyLines[#= index(data)#].ItemListLineID' value='#= ItemListLineID #' />"
             );
             columns.Bound(p => p.ItemListCode).Hidden(true).ClientTemplate("#= ItemListCode #" +
                "<input type='hidden' name='MyLines[#= index(data)#].ItemListCode' value='#= ItemListCode #' />"
             );
             columns.Command(command =>
             {
                 command.Destroy();
             }).Width(200);
         })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
         .Model(m =>
         {
             m.Id(p => p.ItemCode);
             m.Field(p => p.ItemCode).Editable(false);
             m.Field(p => p.Description).Editable(false);
             m.Field(p => p.UoM).Editable(false);
             m.Field(p => p.QtyCC).Editable(true);
             m.Field(p => p.QtyEmployee).Editable(true);
             m.Field(p => p.ItemListLineID).Editable(false);
             m.Field(p => p.ItemListCode).Editable(false);
         })
         .Batch(true)
         .ServerOperation(false)
         // these are dummy action methods that don't really exist.
         .Update("upd", "upd") 
         .Destroy("del", "del")
         .Create("cre", "cre")
    )
    .Navigatable()
)
```

Here's the "index" function:

```
function index(dataItem) {
    var data = $("#RequestLinesGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();

    return data.indexOf(dataItem);
}
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, your solution will post back all the rows of your grid, is there any way to change your declaration to only post changed rows?

Comment: Nope, one would have to check for changed rows in the controller action method.

Comment: Where are you getting Index from? I'm getting an error on that?

Comment: @RyanLege I have added the index function to my answer

Comment: After removing a row and then submitting I am getting a javascript error that the nodetype is null or cannot be found. This only happens when I remove not when I add

Comment: I am having same issue, if I create new project then it works fine but in my project it does not work. I tried to create new controller, view and model but still it does not work in my project. I have aspx and mvc combined in my project home it does not have anything to do with it.

Comment: First, Awesome answer.  This has helped me tremendously.  Second, for anyone coming across this answer and wondering what 'MyLines' is..  It is the name of your Collection/Enumerable/List on your parent view model.  Its probably obvious to you veterans, but it took me a minute or 2 to figure out while debugging.  Thanks Shawn!

Comment: @ShawndeWet you are a live saver, I owe you a cookie :p

Answer (score 1):

So here is part of a solution to your question. I extended the kendo Datasource, so you can call this function and get all the updated, deleted, created items out. Just turn it into json and send it back with the rest of your form fields. I have got this working now. Thought I would share.

```
kendo.data.DataSource.prototype.GetUnsavedData = function () {
    var that = this,
        idx,
        length,
        created = [],
        updated = [],
        destroyed = that._destroyed,
    allRows = [],
        data = that._flatData(that._data);

    for (idx = 0, length = data.length; idx < length; idx++) {
        if (data[idx].isNew()) {
            created.push(data[idx]);
        } else if (data[idx].dirty) {
            updated.push(data[idx]);
        }
    }

    allRows = created.concat(updated).concat(destroyed);
    var allRowsJSON = JSON.stringify(allRows);
    return allRowsJSON;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by [codebeastie](http://blog.codebeastie.com/return-grid-contents-within-form-post/) and @user1878526 to produce the following hybrid idea - simply returning the grid as a list of strings to the controller save action:

Controller:

```
Function Save(ThisForum As myModel, gridData As List(Of String)) As ActionResult
```

View:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function (event) {
    var grid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var data = grid.dataSource.view();
    var input;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var s = JSON.stringify(data[i]).replace(/["']/g, "");
        input = $("<input>", { type: 'hidden', name: 'data[' + i + ']', value: s });
        $(this).append($(input));
    }
})
```

This can then be parsed in the controller reasonably easily by `Split`ing on commas and colons.