# kendo ui grid with custom editing and data arriving empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have this Kendo UI Grid in a ASP-NET MVC Web Application with Kendo UI

```
/*GRID*/
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("contactos")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
       ..........
    })
    .ToolBar(toolBar =>
        {
            toolBar.Create();
            toolBar.Save();
        })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Groupable().Pageable().Sortable().Scrollable().Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
                    {
                        .......
                    }
                )
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetAllContactsClientJSON", "CrmCProfile", new { Id_Cliente = @ViewBag.Id_Cliente }))
        .Create(create => create.Action("AddContact", "CrmCProfile"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateContact", "CrmCProfile").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
    )
```

When I do Update, in the next controller Action :

```
 /*Controller Action Update */

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult UpdateContact([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,IEnumerable<ContactosClientesVM> contactos)
{
    if (contactos != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      ...
     }
     return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
    }
}
```

The IEnumerable contactos = null,

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Kendo Grid is not a form element and it cannot be simply posted to the server. 
You can take advantage of the templates that the Grid provide and create hidden elements based on the different row models which to be submitted to the server.

Check:
[Post the Kendo Grid Data on Form Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948248/post-the-kendo-grid-data-on-form-submit)