# MVC 4 maintaining state throughout application

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 application that consists of one page and a large form where I want to collect data and submit at the end (my initial plan was to use `@Html.BeginForm()`).

The problems I'm running into are that it can take some time to fill out and I'm struggling to keep track of all this and capture it on post submission at the end ([kendo ui issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555137/submit-form-with-kendo-mvc-grid-and-other-elements) - they have examples for dealing with this but I don't really like any of them). Also there is the issue of losing data if the page refreshes or something happens before submit. Saving to the db before the end is not an option. I have thought about using a `Session` variable to save my model state but I get mixed opinions when researching this and I'm not sure if it's right for what I'm trying to do.

I'm wondering if using `Session` here is a good idea or if anyone has any other suggestions. Any advice will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If saving to the db is not an option, then Session is one way to go. Another option could be saving to the browser's local storage depending on what browsers the app supports. Session is not always the best option because of its dictionary nature, volatility, additional considerations for load balancing scenarios, etc etc... but it is there for a reason. If it does what you need it to, use it.